# What is preventing the link in AngularJS from appearing in ng-view?

Tags: angularjs

I am constructing my first AngularJS app with Cordova CLI and testing in Chrome. As it now stands, when you click on a link (as "#/gallery_details"), the page (at "/views/gallery_details.html") does not appear. Rather, the browser goes from

```
[...]/foundation5/www/index.html
```

to

```
[...]/foundation5/www/index.html#/gallery_details
```

and leaves the index.html content as is. However, the ng-repeat directive is working fine, populating the Foundation 5 layout correctly.

After researching many sites, it looks like my setup is correct (though the pages I studied coded thing slightly differently).

Can you tell me where I am off in my coding?

Chrome Tools shows this error, which I don't know how to solve:

**Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/unpr?p0=%24templateRequestProvider%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24route%20%3C-%20ngViewDirective**

**galleryApp.js:**

```
    var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/gallery_details', {
                templateUrl: 'views/gallery_details.html',
                controller: 'RouteController'
            }) 
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            }); $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);

/* 
http://stephanebegaudeau.tumblr.com/post/48776908163/everything-you-need-to-understand-to-start-with
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07
*/
    app.controller('RouteController,' ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('views/gallery_details.html').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.message ='<a href="../index.html">Return</a>"';
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.message ='ERROR! <a href="../index.html">Return</a>"';
        });

    }]);
```

**index.html:**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="en" data-ng-app="app">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />

    <!-- in the <head> according to https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07 -->
    <script src= "angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/galleryApp.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/galleryCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    </head>

  [...]

    <div class="row" data-ng-controller="galleryCtrl">
                <div class="large-3 small-4 columns" data-ng-repeat="x in names | filter: id()"> 
                  <div style="line-height:150px; display:block;"><img src="{{ x.photo }}"></div>

                  <div class="panel">
                    <h5>{{ x.name2 }}</h5>
                    <a href="#/gallery_details">More</a><br>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div data-ng-view></div>
```

Comment: Make sure that `angular.min.js` and `angular-route.js` are the same version.

Comment: tasseKATT, thanks! I downloaded v1.3.10 for both at https://code.angularjs.org/ and the problem persists.

Comment: I suspect I am using $http.get wrong.

Comment: I'm doing this wholly on my computer. Do these pages have to be on a server to work?